# Front diff mount bushing eyelet split in half?

Tags: nissan, bushing, xterra, front-differential

04 Nissan Xterra, the front diff is attached to the frame with 4 bushings, two on the front on the frame cross-member and two on the back on a rear mount bracket. Had the truck on jack stands trying to diagnose a dragging front caliper and noticed things shacking up front - and holy shit!!

Here's a diagram, it's a bit hard to explain:
[image]

Here's a pic of the split eyelet, you can see how it's detached from the rubber bushing...
[image]

A few years back I had a shop install a 'diff drop kit' with offset bushings to help adjust the CV axle angle seeing as the truck has a 3" suspension lift. The kit simply used special bushings where the inner hole wasn't centered like a OE bushing but offset. Wondering if that had anything to do with it? But I can't really think how it would...

Any thoughts!?? This rear mount just unbolts from the diff so I'm thinking I'll just fine a replacement and unbolt/rebolt and not worry about pulling the whole diff and replacing the front bushings. Any thoughts?